# How to call v-for variable to function

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I am using vue3 and c_cid is important for me to implement the function. here is what I have.

```html
<div
  class="client_card"
  type="button"
  v-for="c in all_clients"
  data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#add_delievery_address"
>
  <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #1267aa">
    <button @click="createDelieveryAddress(`{{ c.c_cid }}`)">
      Submit Delivery Address
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you see in

```js
createDelieveryAddress(`{{ c.c_cid }}`)
```

, I cannot call `c.c_id` inisde the `v-for`. Here is my JS:

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "ClientAll",
  data() {
    return {
      all_clients: [],
      client: {
        c_fullname: null,
        c_address_1: null,
        c_address_2: null,
        c_city: null,
        c_insert_date: null,
        c_post_code: null,
        c_cid: null //this is important for me to call function createDelieveryAddress
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createDelieveryAddress(c_cid) {
      console.log("cannot called c_cid")
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I call `c_cid` inside the modal? I've tried `{{ }}` and `` but no help.

Comment: the `button` should have `type` not the div, how is your question related to firebase and google cloud?

Answer (score 1):

`<button @click="createDelieveryAddress(c.c_cid)">Submit Delivery Address</button>`

shall do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need interpolation or string literals here, as @RenaudTarnec's answer already pointed out.

However, using

```html
<button @click="createDelieveryAddress(c.c_cid)" />
```

will invoke `createDeliveryAddress` immediately, when the component is mounted, not when the button is pressed.

Unless `createDeliveryAddress` is a function which ***should*** be called at mount, returning another function, which should be invoked  when the button is clicked, you should probably use:

```html
<button @click="() => createDelieveryAddress(c.c_cid)" />
```

---

That aside, the relation between `client.c_cid` (coming from `client`) and `c.c_cid` (coming from looping through members of `allClients`), is quite unclear.

If you need more help, please shed more light on your data structure and the expected result/behavior.